# functional way to set value in nested array to null

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to go through both objects below and if there is no assignment with the selected datetime between the start_timestamp and the end_timestamp the values table.translateY, table.translateX and masterId in the layouts object should be set to null.

How can I achieve that?

My try:

```
    layouts = layouts.forEach(function(layout){
        assignments.forEach(function(assignment){
            layout.tables.map(function(table){
              if (table.id !== assignment.tableId && assignment.start_timestamp >= timestamp && !assignment.end_timestamp < timestamp) {
                table.translateY = null;
                table.translateX = null;
                table.masterId = null;
              }
          });
      })
    });
```

My layouts object looks like that:

```
{  
      "id":31,
      "stationId":31,
      "tables":[  
         {  
            "id":652,
            "number":"040",
            "x":1285,
            "y":527,
            "length":98,
            "breadth":69,
            "rotation":0,
            "shape":"rectangle",
            "translateX":0,
            "translateY":0,
            "masterId":null,
            "seats":4
         },
         {
         ...
         }
       ]
}
```

My assignment object looks like this:

```
[ Assignment {
    id: 6798,
    tableId: 685,
    guestGroupId: 60725,
    start_timestamp: undefined,
    end_timestamp: undefined },
  Assignment {...}
]
```

Comment: 1) To solve your issue at hand: Use composable getters/setters aka Lenses 2) To solve the underlying issue: Use tagged unions (of objects/records) rather than objects/records to model your data structure, so that you can avoid `null` from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to do an assignment lookup in your map
It's really the only way. You don't want to be nesting loops of different data sets.

```
const newLayouts = layouts.map(layout =>
  layout.tables.map(table => {
    const assignment = assignments.find(({ id }) => id === table.id);
    if (
      assignment &&
      assignment.start_timestamp >= timestamp &&
      !assignment.end_timestamp < timestamp
    ) {
      return {
        ...table,
        translateY: null,
        translateX: null,
        masterId: null
      };
    }
    // Else
    return table;
  })
);
```